# JSP for loop based on number of records to insert footer

Tags: java, jsp, loops, for-loop

Prior to my question on 
[JSP Insert footer based on condition in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101453/jsp-insert-footer-based-on-condition-in-for-loop/17101636?noredirect=1#17101636), I am wondering if I can do something based on this situation:

I have number of records, x. The number of records I want to print per page is say 35, so let's say x=100, I would like to print 3 pages, 2 pages that contain 35 records each and the last page prints 30.

How do I go about doing it?

I can only think of...

```
for (int i=0; i<35; i++)
{
    //loop records and print 35 records in first page
}
for (int i=36; i<70;i++)
{
    // loop second page of another 35 records for printing.
}
for (int i=71;i<totalrecords;i++)
{
   // loop last page...
}
```

Looks like I have to use nested loops for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is better :)

```
int totalRecords = 10;
int pageCounter=0;
int rowsCounter=3;
for(int i=0;i<totalRecords;i++){
    if(i%rowsCounter==0){
        pageCounter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Record :"+i+" on Page:"+pageCounter);
}
```

This is obviously for 10 records, with 3 results on each page. When you run it this is the output:

> Record :0 on Page:1
>
> Record :1 on Page:1
>
> Record :2 on Page:1
>
> Record :3 on Page:2
>
> Record :4 on Page:2
>
> Record :5 on Page:2
>
> Record :6 on Page:3
>
> Record :7 on Page:3
>
> Record :8 on Page:3
>
> Record :9 on Page:4